# Can I use linear model on each variable to determine which variables are important?

Tags: feature-selection

Suppose we have a n*p matrix X and a n*1 matrix Y, where n is the number of samples and p is the number of variables. p>>n. Also suppose this data is from a biology field experiment. My goal is to select the potential biomarkers (variables).

I know there are a bunch of variable selection tools, such as stepwise procedure, criterion based methods and other methods that are nested with the algorithms (random forest, PLS, SVM etc.). But I think the aim of these methods is to build a model to make a good prediction accuracy, FOLLOWED by telling people in this model, which variables are relatively important.

In my opinion, because my goal is not to predict but to select the possible biomarkers which will be confirmed in further experiments, can I simply do linear regression between each variable and Y and see which are significant and also have a high R^2 score?

Thank you!

I understand this is not a simple answer question. Please provide a relatively thorough description of your idea.

Comment: Have you tried elastic net? This algorithm would choose the most important variables out of p variables.

Comment: @williamchiu Hi William, thanks for your response. To my knowledge, elastic net is somewhat a combination of ridge regression and lasso. Though I don't have a lot of experience of using elastic net, I guess elastic net is just one of tons of statistical methods, like stepwise procedure, AIC BIC criterion based method, etc, which helps to build models and select variables. However, what confuses me here is that a lot of scientists use these and other similar methods to select variables, especially in biology related fields, where they try to select biomarkers.

Comment: @williamchiu  Their aim is not to predict but to select variable. I don't understand why not just do simple linear regression on each variable and determine which variables are potential biomarkers based on their t statistic?  People may say multidisciplinary, but when selecting biomarker, do we really concern about it?

Comment: You are correct. Elastic net is a compromise between the lasso and the ridge. Elastic net is an alternative to stepwise regression.

Comment: I'm not a scientist, but I assume you are searching for a few biomarkers that predict a disease.  This is a really hard job because a disease may be associated with a *combination* of biomarkers rather than by a single biomarker. Given p markers, there are $2^p$ possible combinations. There is no server in the world that can calculate that many regressions. Hence, you need shortcuts.  Some of these shortcuts are stepwise, elastic net, random forest, and boosted trees.

Comment: Looking at individual regressions for each variable will perform poorly and select a lot of useless variables for further exploration (besides being hopefully unpublishable in a decent journal).

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to regress on one variable at a time because of the ''omitted variable bias'' (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias)

Comment: @Björn I am very interested in your response. Thank you. Can you please be more specific? In what aspect does it perform poorly? I understand that by looking at individual regression, there will be a lot of useless variables. However, will it be possible that when using other fancy methods, like PLS, useful biomarkers which are truly biologically functional to a body response, will be neglected? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The proposed method seems very unlikely to produce useful results. The problem I would anticipate is lots of false positive results.

For example, suppose we wish to predict $y$ and have two predictors $x$ and $z$. Let

$y = x + \epsilon_1$

$z = x + \epsilon_2$

Then the proposed method is likely to select both $x$ and $z$. Any decent linear model involving $x$ and $z$ simultaneously will lead you to see that $z$ is not required in the presence of $x$.

This might sound unlikely, but as you add more variables to a model you're more likely to already have accounted for all the signal.

The upshot of this is that you may have to do lots of unnecessary additional experiments.

I would suggest the OP investigate LASSO regression. This is set up nicely for $p \gg n$ regression problems where variable selection is required. 
In general while you'd guess this area should have been fully developed for linear models, the $p \gg n$ variable selection problem is still an active research area.

---

```
X = rnorm(1000)
Y = X + rnorm(1000)
Z = X + rnorm(1000)
summary(lm(Y ~ Z))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ Z)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8207 -0.8326 -0.0109  0.8688  3.8545 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.02033    0.03998  -0.509    0.611    
Z            0.50815    0.02840  17.895   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.264 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2429,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2422 
F-statistic: 320.2 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

summary(lm(Y ~ X + Z))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X + Z)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5276 -0.6879 -0.0111  0.6992  3.4331 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.021569   0.032455  -0.665    0.506    
X            1.028787   0.045233  22.744   <2e-16 ***
Z            0.001838   0.032047   0.057    0.954    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.026 on 997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5015,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5005 
F-statistic: 501.6 on 2 and 997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

---

EDIT: On whether the proposed method would mop up all true positives. I would be doubtful.

First, assuming all the true positives were found, then the proposed filtering mechanism based on $R^2$ would still be in trouble. Suppose we added to the truth in our example another variable $q$ which didn't contribute much to overall variation in $y$:

$y = x + 0.1q + \epsilon$

Then $q$ would often have a lower $R^2$ than $z$. So you wouldn't be able to 
trust your ranking mechanism.

---

```
> Q = rnorm(1000)
> Y = X + 0.1*Q + rnorm(1000)
> summary(lm(Y~X+Z+Q))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X + Z + Q)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4460 -0.6397  0.0551  0.6146  3.6106 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.002512   0.032670   0.077 0.938719    
X           0.981008   0.047013  20.867  < 2e-16 ***
Z           0.015557   0.033436   0.465 0.641838    
Q           0.115547   0.032690   3.535 0.000427 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.03 on 996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.487, Adjusted R-squared:  0.4855 
F-statistic: 315.2 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(lm(Y~Z))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ Z)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8912 -0.8182 -0.0121  0.8061  3.7114 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.03833    0.03915   0.979    0.328    
Z            0.51934    0.02785  18.645   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.238 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2583,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2576 
F-statistic: 347.6 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(lm(Y~Q))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ Q)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2620 -0.9772  0.0030  1.0116  4.7014 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.02539    0.04535    0.56    0.576  
Q            0.10861    0.04544    2.39    0.017 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.433 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.005693,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.004696 
F-statistic: 5.714 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: 0.01702
```

---

Also I would anticipate that as the true model for $y$ became more complex, e.g.

$y = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n + q + \epsilon$

Then regression on $q$ alone would end up not seeing the coefficient as significant. The reason for this being that structural variation in $y$ due to $x$ would get swept up in our estimate of the noise $\sigma^2$

The reason for this being that omitting the true variables $x$ our regression's performance gets worse, the mean square error gets bigger, $\hat \sigma^2$ gets bigger and thus the standard error of linear regression coefficients gets worse.

---

Comment: Well explained! Thanks. Can I say that the proposed method in my question  tends to select too many variables (many false positive) while the real variables that we want (true positive) is also within these selected variables?

Comment: And a quick question, what is OP in your sentence "I would suggest the OP investigate LASSO regression"?

Comment: I meant Opening Poster, the person who asked the question.

Comment: Original Poster seems the standard wording, but the meaning is the same. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op

Answer (score 4):

If your predictors (biomarkers) are colinear, univariate regressions may grossly over / underestimate effect sizes, depending on sign of the colinearity and the sign of the product of their effect sizes. This is known as [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox), or in general as omitted-variable bias, as mentioned above. I would therefore not recommend this approach.

I am not aware of a perfect solution for the p>>n case, and neither do I think that one exists. Yet, if the goal is to prioritize predictors for later testing, and you think effects can be well expressed by linear relationships, I would go for a regularization method such as ridge regression and lasso, and simply take the variables that come out with the strongest effects - the advantage over AIC-based model selection is less sensitivity to colinearity in the predictors (because predictors are not removed).

Comment: Thank you Florian Hartig. I appreciate your answer. I checked Simpson's paradox and omitted-variable bias. Firstly, I am not sure how my question is related to the Simpson's paradox. Then, as for omitted-variable bias, which is explained by wiki as "In statistics, omitted-variable bias (OVB) occurs when a model is created which incorrectly leaves out one or more important factors. " I think OVB means we incorrectly replace/delete important variable while leaving unrelated variables in the model. So I think looking at simple regression on each variable actually tries prevent OVB conservatively.

Comment: I have an explanation here https://github.com/biometry/APES/blob/master/LectureNotes/FlorianExamples/Regression/UnivariateMultivariate.md  // Simpson's paradox is a special case of OVB.

Answer (score 0):

Aristotle said that, “The whole is greater than the sum of its parts.” Each simple linear regression is merely testing  a part. However, I imagine that many diseases are associated with combinations of markers (the whole). What you really care about are the combination of markers.  As a result, your algorithm may not work well because you are not testing the combination.

Comment: The opening quotation is common, but arguably not at all apposite. The problem is precisely the opposite, namely that adding more predictors does **not** itself necessarily add much more explanatory power, because the predictors overlap and are correlated . Otherwise all (ideal) models would be arbitrarily complex. So, some special cases aside, the whole is less than the sum of its parts, if anything. The rest of the answer is spot on, naturally.